# How do I correct the arrows alignment and directions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning,shadows.blur,chains,scopes,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
 ->,
    >=Stealth,
    shorten >=1pt,
    shorten <=1pt,
    thick,
    main node/.style={fill=white, draw, font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries, blur shadow, align=center},
    hex/.style={main node, rectangle},
    ell/.style={main node, ellipse},
    blur shadow={shadow opacity=25},
  ]
  %Nodes
   \node [ell] (maintopic)  {Low Water Charges};
   \node [ell] (wp) [left=of maintopic] {Water Pricing Policy};
   \node [ell] (ec) [right=of maintopic] {\parbox[t][][t]{2.8cm}{{Environmental Consequences like Groundwater Depletion}}};
   \node [hex] (lc) [below=of maintopic] {Low \textendash Cost Recovery};
   \node [hex] (lw) [below=of wp] at (-3.5,-2.5) {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Low Willingness to Pay}}};
   \node [hex] (if) [below=of ec] at (4.5,-2.5) {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Inability to Fund adequately O \& M}}};
   \node [hex] (fd) [below=of lw] at (-3,-4.5) {Farmer Dissatisfaction};
    \node [hex] (p) [below=of if] at (4,-4.5){Poor O \& M};
    \node [hex] (pis) [below=of lc] at (0.1,-6.4) {Poor Irrigation Service};
    \node [ell] (la) [below=of wp] at (-7,-2.5) {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Low ability to Pay}}};
    \node [ell] (li) [below=of la] at (-6.5,-3.8) {Low Incomes};
    \node [ell] (ly) [below=of li] at (-5,-5.5) {Low Yields};
    \node [ell] (iae) [below=of ly] {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Inadequate Agricultural Extension}}};
    \node [ell] (ic) [below=of pis] {Institutional Constraints};
    \node [ell] (dpi) [right=of lc] at (3.8,-5) {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Decline in Public Investment}}};
    \node [ell] (ld) [above=of dpi] at (8,-4.5) {\parbox[t][][t]{2.4cm}{{Low / Declining Priority in Planned Funds for Irrigation}}};
    \node [hex] (ps) [right=of pis] at (0.9,-6.8) {\parbox[t][][t]{3cm}{{Poor Irrigation Systems}}};
   %Lines
   \draw[<-] (wp) -- (maintopic);
   \draw[->] (maintopic) -- (ec);
   \draw[->] (maintopic) -- (lc);
   \draw[-] (lc.west) ..  controls +(left:10mm) and +(up:15mm)
    .. (lw.north);
    \draw[-] (lc.east) .. controls +(right:7mm) and + (up:20mm) .. (if.north);
    \draw[-] (lw.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(left:5mm) .. (fd.north);
    \draw[-] (if.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(right:5mm) .. (p.north);
    \draw[-] (fd.south) .. controls +(down:5mm) and +(left:5mm) .. (pis.west);
    \draw[-] (p.south) .. controls +(down:5mm) and +(right:1mm) .. (ps.north);
    \draw[-] (ps.west) .. controls +(down:5mm) and +(right:5mm) .. (pis.east);
    \draw [-] (lc.west) .. controls +(left:20mm) and + (up:2mm) .. (la.north);
    \draw[-] (la.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(left:5mm) .. (li.north);
    \draw[-] (li.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(left:5mm) .. (ly.north);
    \draw[-] (ly.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(left:5mm) .. (pis.west);
    \draw[-] (lc.east) .. controls +(right:15mm) and + (up:15mm) .. (dpi.north);

    \draw[-> ,line width=0.8mm] (lc.southwest) .. controls +(right:10mm) and + (up:22mm) .. (dpi.north);
    \draw[-] (dpi.south) ..  controls +(down:5mm) and +(right:5mm) .. (ps.east);
    \draw[-] (ps.south) .. controls +(down:5mm) and +(right:5mm) .. (pis.east);
    \draw[->] (ic) -- (pis);
    \draw[->] (iae) -- (ly);
    \draw[->] (ld) -- (dpi); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How do I correct the arrows' alignment?

Comment: First error is `southwest`. the correct syntax is `south west`

Comment: I tired east now its working fine. Earlier it was not working. South west syntax is not working. Still the arrow alignment is not proper.

Comment: I am just decomposing the problem. you can't compile with `southwest`. check my answer

Comment: Beside typing error (`southwest` -> `south west`) your figure is far to wide that can be fit in text block! It protrude age border! How you imagine to fit it on page? Is rotated it acceptable solution. BTW, showed image is not entirely clear.  Showed arrows are a bit strange ...

Comment: Good edit. Now I have more question: What do you consider not satisfactory in your current version? what part is to change?

Comment: The flowchart is not forming a complete circle like in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it is not entirely clear, how your image should be:

- Beside typing error `southwest` -> `south west`
- Your figure is far to wide that can be fit in text block! It protrude page border (see image of your code, to it I only add `showframe` that you can see page layout)

[image]

(red lines indicate your document page layout)

- How you imagine to fit it on page? Is rotated figure it acceptable solution?

[image]

MWE for above figure is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4,twoside]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                scopes, shadows.blur, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[hp]
    \centering
\copyrightbox[b]{
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 4mm,
  start chain = H going right,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
  base/.style = {draw, thick, font=\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries,
                 fill=white, minimum height=3ex,
                 text width=7.5em, align=flush center,
                 outer sep=1mm, blur shadow={shadow opacity=30}},
     E/.style = {ellipse, base,  text width=6em, inner xsep=-3pt},
     N/.style = {rectangle, base},
                        ]
%Nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=H}]
\node (n11) [E]  {Water Pricing Policy};
\node (n12) [E]  {Low Water Charges};
\node (n13) [E,text width=10em]
                {Environmental Consequences like Groundwater Depletion};
    \draw[arr]  (n12) -- (n11);
    \draw[arr]  (n12) -- (n13);
   \end{scope}
\node (n2)  [N, below=of n12] {Low -- Cost Recovery};
    \draw[arr]  (n12) -- (n2);
%
\node (n311) [N, below left=of n2.south]    {Low Willingness to Pay};
\node (n312) [N, below=of n311]             {Farmer Dissatisfaction};
    \draw[arr]  (n2.west) to[bend right] (n311.north);
    \draw[arr]  (n311) -- (n312);
%
\node (n321) [E, left =of n311]     {Low ability to Pay};
\node (n322) [E, below=of n321]     {Low Incomes};
\node (n323) [E, below=of n322]     {Low Yields};
    \draw[arr]  (n2.west) to[bend right] (n321.north);
    \draw[arr]  (n321) -- (n322);
    \draw[arr]  (n322) -- (n323);
%
\node (n4) [N, below=of n323.south -| n2]  {Poor Irrigation Service};
    \draw[arr]  (n312)  to[bend right]       ([yshift= 1mm] n4.west);
    \draw[arr]  ([xshift=1mm] n323.south)
                        to[bend right] ([yshift=-1mm] n4.west);
%
\node (n331) [N, below right=of n2.south]
                                {Inability to Fund adequately O \& M};
\node (n332) [N, below=of n331] {Poor \& Ms};
\node (n333) [N, below=of n332] {Poor Irigation System};
    \draw[arr]  (n2.east) to[bend left] (n331.north);
    \draw[arr]  (n331) -- (n332);
    \draw[arr]  (n332) -- (n333);
    \draw[arr]  (n333) to[bend left] ([yshift= 1mm] n4.east);
%
\node (n34) [E, right =of n332]   {Decline in Public Investment};
    \draw[arr]  (n2.east) to[bend left] (n34);
    \draw[arr]  (n34)     to[bend left] ([yshift=-1mm] n4.east);
%
\node (n51) [E, below=of n323 |- n4.south,
             text width=8em]
                                {Inadequate Agricultural Extension};
\node (n52) [E, below=of n4]    {Institutional Constraints};
    \draw[arr]  (n51) -- (n323);
    \draw[arr]  (n52) -- (n4);
%
\node (n6)  [E,above right=of n34.north,
             text width=9em]
             {Low/Declining Priority in Planned Funds for Irrigation};
    \draw[arr]  (n6) -- (n34);
\end{tikzpicture}
}{Source: World Bank, 1999}
\caption{Caption text}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By correcting `southwest` to `south west`:

[image]

My question is what is the correct alignment? How do you want it?

By replacing each `south west` by `east`, I get :

[image]

Comment: I have shared an image in my question. I need a flow chart of a similar type.